# Hiding Excel DAX measures

Tags: excel, dax, measure

I created an excel spreadsheet with many power pivots and power charts.  I created many measures through the "add measure" functionality.

I went into the Data Model and clicked on "Hide from client tool" for these measures.

However, although hidden, they can still go into Power Pivot --> Measures --> Manage Measures... and see/edit the formulas.

I will send this spreadsheet to many users.  Is there a way to prevent the users from seeing the measures.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow. I've been protecting the workbook for years (which prevents access to the Power Pivot window) under the assumption that that would be sufficient to also prevent the scenario you describe. Clearly not, as I've just confirmed. I'll be following this thread closely hoping that there's a solution, as, if not, that seems to be a very large loophole indeed.

Comment: @JosWoolley, any luck finding a work around?  So far no one suggested a solution in this thread.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I found [this 2019 official response from an MS representative](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/in-excel-for-office-365-is-there-anyway-to-protect/41a4ffc8-a3a5-45e7-99c5-fb25b9f13b5a), which seems to confirm that it's not possible to protect measures. I'm as shocked as you are.